# Use "SRTM Downloader Plugin" with "QGIS 3.4"

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3, dem, srtm

Edit (TL;DR): As [Gabriel De Luca](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/133276/gabriel-de-luca) pointed out in his [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/348615/157068) there is an [open GitHub ticket about the issue](https://github.com/hdus/SRTM-Downloader/issues/12).

---

I would like to use "SRTM Downloader Plugin" with "QGIS 3.4" (OS: Win7, 64-bit).

Now if I start the plugin

[image: QGIS start SRTM Downloader Plugin]

and run it

[image: run SRTM Downloader Plugin]

by clicking on

1. Set canvas extent and
2. Download

nothing happens. According to a tutorial I must now set my credentials in a modal. But no modal pops up. And the process gets stuck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have tested the plugin and it is working fine in my machine.

[image: 1]

---

One common way to download (SRTM among other) data is searching it in [Earth Explorer](https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov) site.

All the information about how to use the site is in their [Help page](https://lta.cr.usgs.gov/EEHelp/ee_help).

If you want to download just that image, you can do it from the *Download* link provided in the following page:

- https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/metadata/8360/SRTM1N51E011V3/

Comment: Dear Gabriel, thank you. This is very strange. Any suggestions why I don't get the login modal. I guess you also don't have a clue, have you?

Comment: Hi Axel, No, I don't know, but I found an open [ticket about that in the SRTM-Downloader GitHub repository](https://github.com/hdus/SRTM-Downloader/issues/12). I have tested it in QGIS 3.4.14, Win10 64-bit machine.

Comment: 3.4.15 Win7 64-bit here